# End while loop by EOF only once

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, scanf, eof

I am trying to solve this problem but unfortunately I can't find any solution.

I have this loop that I want to break with `EOF` but it always requires it twice instead once.

```
    do {
        int input = scanf("%d", &elements[count++]);
        if (input == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        if (input == 0) {
            wrongInput = true;
            return;
        }
    } while (1);
```

I also tried it like this but it didn't work either:

```
    while ((int input = scanf("%d", &elements[count++])) != EOF) {
        if (input == 0) {
            wrongInput = true;
            return;
        }
    }
```

I always had to press <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> twice. This is the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int count = 0;

int elements[1000000];

int diff = 0;
int optCount = 0;
int firstElement[1000000];
int secondElement[1000000];

bool wrongInput = false;

void inputArr() {

    bool emptyCheck = false;
    // Perform a do-while loop

    do {
        int input = scanf("%d", &elements[count++]);
        if (input == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        if (input == 0) {
            wrongInput = true;
            return;
        }
        if (input != 1) {
            emptyCheck = true;
        }
    } while (1);

    // Resize the array size to count
    elements[count];
    if (emptyCheck == true) {
        elements[count--];
    }
}

void farthestMax(int b[], int n) {
    // To store maximum element in the range i to n
    int suffix_max[n];
    suffix_max[n - 1] = b[n - 1];
    for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        suffix_max[i] = (suffix_max[i + 1] > b[i]) ? suffix_max[i + 1] : b[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int low = i + 1, high = n - 1, ans = -1;

        while (low <= high)
        {
            int mid = (low + high) / 2;

            // If current element in the suffix_max is greater than b[i] then move right
            if (suffix_max[mid] > b[i])
            {
                ans = mid;
                low = mid + 1;
            }
            else
                high = mid - 1;
        }

        // Print the required answer
        int currentDiff = ans - i;
        if (ans != -1) {
            if (currentDiff == diff) {
                firstElement[optCount] = i;
                secondElement[optCount] = ans;

                optCount++;
            }
            if (currentDiff > diff) {
                diff = currentDiff;
                optCount = 1;
                firstElement[0] = i;
                secondElement[0] = ans;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("Input numbers:\n");
    inputArr();
    if (wrongInput == true) {
        printf("Wrong input.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("\n");
    farthestMax(elements, count);
    if (optCount == 0) {
        printf("Cant find.\n");
    } else {
        for (int i = optCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            printf("%d: %d - %d\n", diff + 1, firstElement[i], secondElement[i]);
        }
        printf("Options: %d\n", optCount);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mre] and sample input which provokes the obserbed problem.

Comment: IDK how Linux behaves but with Windows you must press Ctrl+Z immediately after one newline and before another.

Comment: Aside: better not to do `count++` until you know it's a good input.

Comment: Is the shown code properly copy-pasted from your program? You don't happen to have a leading or trailing space in your format string? Or some other code which could read or catch the first or second `EOF` outside the loop? Have you used a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line to see what really happens?

Comment: There is suspicious-looking use of global variables.

Comment: That depends on terminal. You cant change it using "plain" C

Comment: Here is the whole code for more context: https://codeshare.io/8p0neD

Comment: @TeodorOtkovic I would suggest not using EOF as an indication of the end of input if you do not work with real files. Find another method

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is expected that you post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the **shortest *complete*** code that shows the problem. People aren't willing to go to an external link and read through the whole code, they prefer to copy/paste a simple code and try it, in just a few seconds. May I suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Whatever source you're using to learn C it unfortunately doesn't do a very good job. All those global variables are a bad habit. And the whole "[r]esize the array size to count" part just doesn't do anything useful. Arrays just can't be resized. And even if you made the arrays very large, you still have no bounds-checking for input overflow.

Comment: You need to press Ctrl+D on a line of its own, otherwise it won't work,

Comment: `elements[count];` is a glorified no-op. And, `elements[count--] ;` can be `count--;`

Comment: _"I am trying to solve this problem but unfortunately I can't find any solution."_  This statement is unnecessary because it should be true of every question asked on Stack Overflow.  I know you're just establishing how you feel, but we all know already that you're here with a question you don't have an answer for.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you observe is a side effect of the terminal handling of the special character <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> by default associated to the `EOF` terminal function as explained in the `termios` man page:

```
     EOF     Special character on input and is recognized if the ICANON flag
             is set.  When received, all the bytes waiting to be read are 
             immediately passed to the process, without waiting for a
             newline, and the EOF is discarded.  Thus, if there are no bytes
             waiting (that is, the EOF occurred at the beginning of a line),
             a byte count of zero is returned from the read(), representing
             an end-of-file indication.  If ICANON is set, the EOF character
             is discarded when processed.  NL Special character on input and 
             is recognized if the ICANON flag is set.  It is the line
             delimiter `\n'.
```

When you read input with `scanf("%d", ...)` in a loop, the `scanf` function reads the characters, skipping initial whitespace and converts the digits until it gets a non digit input or the end of file from the terminal.  The terminal is line buffered by default, so user input is flushed to the caller when the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> or in some special circumstances. If you type <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> at the end of a non empty line, the line contents are flushed to the process.  In this case, `scanf` will eventually try and continue reading from standard input because a short read count is not considered an end iof file, whereas if you type <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> at the beginning of an empty line, or just after a flush, the read request from the terminal will return `0`, which the stream reading functions will interpret as the end of file.

Hence you may need to type <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> twice if you are not at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 0):

> want to break with EOF but it always requires **it** twice instead once.

The bolded **it**, a <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>, is not always an `EOF`.

In OP's case, 2 <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>s only sent 1 end-of file signal.